# An identity related to Chebyshev polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, number-theory

Let $n=2m$ be a positive even integer. I can prove that $$1+\sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^k \frac{n^2(n^2-2^2)\cdots(n^2-(2k-2)^2)}{(2k)!}=(-1)^m$$
using hypergeometric identity $${}_2F_1(-m,b;c;1)=\frac{(c-b)_m}{(c)_m}.$$ Does anyone know a simpler direct proof.